# Enter a new line in ttile Table antd

Tags: reactjs, antd

My header title too long, i want it enter in a new line
[image]

I try to css but it will impact to another table
This is my config in column
 `{ title: 'This title needs enter new line', dataIndex: 'name', align: 'left', width: 100, },`

Comment: Have you tried "\n"? Like 'This title needs \n enter new line'

Comment: thanks but i created new className and css on it, that's so quick